# Can we load dynamic Angular dialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I noticed that the dialog for Angular can do custom dialog by loading an html file (or whatever file in html format) like this:

```
$mdDialog.show({
   controller: DialogController,
   templateUrl: tempUrl,
});
```

My question would be, can we instead of loading the `tempUrl`, make the tempUrl a template where we can dynamically load content into?

I have tried to add `ng-control` in my `tempUrl` like this:

`<md-dialog aria-label="test"><md-content ng-controller="dynamicContent">`

And then use `{{scope.property}}` to manipulate the content but failed. What would be the correct approach for this?

P.S. I think this might have to do with the fact that the dynamic content I generated was done asynchronously.

Here is my code:

```
  $scope.showCardDes = function(card) {
    var tempUrl = card.link;
    tempUrl = tempUrl.replace('sometext','othertext');
    tempUrl = tempUrl + '.json?api_key=xxx';
    $log.debug(tempUrl);
    $.ajax({
      url: tempUrl,
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $log.debug(data);
        $scope.description = data.results[0].description;
      },
      error: function(status) {
        $log.debug(status);
      }
    });
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'detail.html',
    });
  };
  $scope.test = 'test';
```

For those who want to see the code with `$http`:

```
$http({
  url: tempUrl,
  method: 'GET',
}).success(function(data) {
    $log.debug(data);
    detail = data;
    $scope.description = data.results[0].description;
  }).
  error(function(status) {
    $log.debug(status);
  });
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: DialogController,
  templateUrl: 'detail.html',
});
$scope.test = 'test';
```

And here is what I set up in my dialog html:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Hi there.">
  <md-content style="padding:4%" ng-controller="dynamicContent">
    <p>
      {{description}}
    </p>
    <p>
      {{test}}
    </p>
  </md-content>
  <div class="md-actions" layout="row">
    <md-button ng-click="hide()">Go Back</md-button>
  </div>
</md-dialog>
```

Apparently the 'test' shows up fine by the 'description' does not because the latter involves an aync process. BTW, if I `console.log(scope.description)` it will actually show the correct content - I assume that the dialog just loaded before the description was loaded...perhaps it was even loaded when the page was loaded.

I tried using `.then()` on `$http` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should specify which third party module you are using that gives you the `$mdDialog` service. There is no one standard Angular dialog service. Also, try using the Angular `$http` service instead of `$.ajax()`.

Comment: @GregL A fork from Angular Material. My code is actually done through `$http`. I just translated to `$.ajax` because more people are familiar with `$.ajax`.

Comment: **Don't** try to translate like that, it will just cause you to get invalid feedback. You should be posting code that is as similar to your real code as possible. You can assume that anybody who knows Angular knows `$http` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky and simple at the same time. It's not because you are running `$http` or `$.ajax` asynchronously, bus has to do with the fact that the scope of the dialog is not updated.

Here:

```
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: DialogController,
  templateUrl: 'detail.html',
  scope: $scope,
});
```

Comment: The problem with passing the $scope to the Dialog is that when the Dialog is closed, the $scope is destroyed.  Setting preserveScope to true doesn't seem to correct this issue either.